# Call method on specific instance of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What I want to do is probalby pretty simple. I'm looking for the right scope/class method/instance method to do the following:

```
author = Author.first

articles = author.articles
```

I currently reach the same result with this code, which is probably not the best way:

```
author = Author.first
articles = Article.author(id)
```

Together with this class method in the Article class.

```
def self.articles(author_id)
  where(author_id: author_id)
end
```

How can I improve the code?

Comment: What's wrong with using `author.articles.find(:id)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up your associations like this:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Then you can do `author.articles`, which returns an association with all the articles by that author.

You can read more about setting up associations in the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark).

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I can just to author.article without any additional method. ._.